# Laravel creating default object from empty value error

Tags: laravel

I'm getting a 'creating default object from empty value' error.

```
$roomtype = Roomtype::where('name', '=' ,$roomtype_name)->first();

$roomtype -> availability -=1 ;
$roomtype -> save();
return $roomtype;
```

`$roomtype` is not returning NULL.

> $roomtype->availabilty-=1

also returns a value.
I tried this in php artisan tinker and it works perfectly.
Then why is it not working in my controller?

Comment: where and how do you set `$roomtype_name`? also show the full error

Comment: Check in DB you have a same $roomtype_name as name in your Roomtype table